# Hay alguna diferencia en connotación entre las palabras hablar y decir?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

Estaba viendo el significado de 2 palabras en otro idioma y una es traducida al español como "hablar" y la otra como "decir". Eso me hizo preguntarme, tenemos alguna diferencia en nuestro idioma entre estas 2 palabras, o quieren decir exactamente lo mismo?

Comment: ¿Se puede saber cuál es el otro idioma?

Comment: El idioma es japonés

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Diferencias gramaticales:

- *[hablar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JvzNhyI)* es intransitivo en casi todas sus acepciones. Es transitivo en *«hablar un idioma»* y es pronominal cuando significa "tener trato o comunicación con alguien".
- *[decir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BxLriBU%7C)* es transitivo en todas sus acepciones comunes, y es pronominal cuando significa "pensar" (*«Me dije que...»*).
- Por ser intransitivo, *hablar* no se usa para el discurso indirecto como *decir* (*«Ella me dijo que...»*), ya que no puede llevar una oración subordinada como objeto.

Diferencias semánticas:

- *hablar* se refiere a la facultad del habla más o menos en abstracto y al ejercicio de esa facultad sin importar tanto su contenido: decimos que una persona *habla mal, mucho, en voz alta, en varios idiomas*, es decir, nos referimos **al modo en que habla, no a lo que expresa**.
- *decir*, por el contrario, se refiere **al contenido expresado, sin importar tanto su modo**, hasta el punto en que usamos el verbo aunque no se trate literalmente de palabras dichas de una persona a otra, sino también cuando se trata de palabras escritas hace siglos en un libro, enviadas por carta o e-mail, etc.: decimos que una persona o un libro *dice esto o aquello*.

Hasta cierto punto se pueden convertir algunas expresiones con *decir* en expresiones con *hablar* y viceversa usando complementos. Con *decir* nos interesa lo dicho; podemos también decir de qué modo lo dijo, pero no siempre de la misma manera que con *hablar*: decimos *habla alto* pero *dice (algo) en voz alta*. A la inversa, con *hablar* nos interesa el acto del habla o la comunicación, pero podemos añadir el tema: *«este libro habla de...»*.

Seguramente hay más pero creo que esta diferencia de enfoque (en el acto y su modalidad vs. en el contenido expresado) es la principal.

Answer (score 4):

Como ya te han respondido, la diferencia principal entre "hablar" y "decir" es tanto gramatical como de significado. Son, en definitiva, dos palabras bien distintas, aunque a veces se pueden intercambiar como si fueran sinónimos.

Si lo que tú buscas es, como plantea la pregunta, una diferencia de *connotación*, entonces hay que aclarar que eso depende del contexto en el que se dicen, ya que el *valor* connotativo de una palabra (su "significado oculto", por decirlo de alguna manera) es relativo.

En una oración como la siguiente

> El diputado *habló* mucho pero *dijo* poco.

las palabras están significando lo que indica la primera definición del diccionario: *hablar* es "emitir palabras" y *decir* es "manifestar el pensamiento con palabras". Sin embargo, son palabras opuestas por su connotación: "hablar" es negativo (las palabras son solo sonidos) mientras que "decir" es positivo (las palabras contienen ideas). Esta oposición de significados en esta oración en concreto es una diferencia de connotación.

Comment: Muy bueno el ejemplo para mostrar el contraste.